# Pascal - not writing to file

Tags: freepascal, file-manipulation

Howdy, Pascal masters!
I've got a file type of custom records:

```
DBCell = record
    Name: string[10];
    Surname: string[15];
    Balance:integer;
    OpenDate: record
        year: integer;
        month: 1..12;
        day:1..31
    end;
    AccountN: string[10];
end;
DBFile = file of DBCell;
```

And functions, that open and add new element to file:

```
procedure Fopenf(var F:DBFile; var FName:string; var FOpened:boolean);
begin
    Assign(F,FName);

    rewrite(F);

    FOpened:=true;
end;

procedure InsN(var F:DBFile;var cell:DBCell;var FOpened:boolean);
begin
        Write(F,cell);
        Close(F);
        Rewrite(F);
        Writeln('Added');
        FOpened:=false;
end;
```

Problem is, nothing is actually written to file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 'rewrite' call in InsN. 'Rewrite' creates a new file, so by calling it at the end of your program, you are creating a new, empty file!

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I've done any Pascal, but IIRC `Rewrite` truncates the file. You should use `Append`.

You don't need the `Rewrite()` after inserting a record in the file:

```
procedure InsN(var F:DBFile;var cell:DBCell;var FOpened:boolean);
begin
    Write(F,cell);
    Close(F);
    Writeln('Added');
    FOpened:=false;
end;
```

If you don't want to truncate the file every time you open it:

```
procedure Fopenf(var F:DBFile; var FName:string; var FOpened:boolean);
begin
    Assign(F,FName);

    append(F);

    FOpened:=true;
end;
```

Comment: You can't append() to file of custom records. You can reset() file and change pointer to the end of it, though. Anyway, problem's solved, thanks for help.

Comment: @Nordvind since your problem is solved, it would be polite to select some of the answers as the correct one by clicking on the big "V" at left :)